# get the tick labels from a plot and use for another plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get the values of `xticks` from one plot and then use these values for another plot but set the new ticks as 10 to the power of the other plot's ticks. The following lines doesn't do the job I am aiming for

```
labels=[item for item in ax1.get_xticklabels()]
ax2.set_xticklabels(['$10^{{{:d}}}$'.format(int(i)) for i in labels])
```

I will appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: set the same number of ticks for the axis and set the minimum to 10**x[0] and the maximum to 10**x[-1]  ... matplotlib should take care of the rest ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I make plots in a script for a sanity check for 10 to 20 cases and the lower and upper limits changes in each quite bit and I don't want to fix it. I would like to find a way to tune the limits of two plots with each other.

Answer (score 0):

What about sharing axes ? This will fix the same limits and number of ticks for `ax1` and `ax2` :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True)
ax1 = ax[0]
ax2 = ax[1]
```

Then your code will do the trick since you are sure that both subplots have the same `xticks`

```
labels = [item for item in ax2.get_xticklabels()]
ax2.set_xticklabels(['$10^{{{:d}}}$'.format(int(i)) for i in labels])
```